# Converting a Boolean Factor to a Integer Factor

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a column which  has values of True and False with two levels True and False.

How can I convert this to a column of 1 and 0s with levels 1 and 0 in R?

Comment: To get it as a number you can do `as.numeric(var)` and as a factor you can do `factor(as.numeric(variable)`

Comment: Why am i getting 1s and 2s instead of 1s and 0s?

Comment: Factors are coded internally as 1-based consecutive integers. So boolean factors `FALSE/TRUE` become integers `1/2`. But they are still displayed as `0/1`, those are their *labels*. To convert to integer, use `as.integer(as.character(boolean))`.

Comment: If you just want 1s and 0s you can actually just do `+var`

Answer (score 0):

I guess your data is like the following, which contains a `factor` column with `TRUE` and `FALSE`.

```
df <- data.frame(x = factor(c(T, T, F, F)))

#       x
# 1  TRUE
# 2  TRUE
# 3 FALSE
# 4 FALSE

str(df)

# 'data.frame': 4 obs. of  1 variable:
#  $ x: Factor w/ 2 levels "FALSE","TRUE": 2 2 1 1
```

To convert it to a `factor` column with levels 1 and 0:

```
factor(df$x, labels = c(0, 1))

# [1] 1 1 0 0
# Levels: 0 1
```

To convert it to a `integer` column with 1 and 0:

```
as.integer(df$x) - 1

# [1] 1 1 0 0
```

or

```
+as.logical(df$x)

# [1] 1 1 0 0
```

It depends on which type of column you want.

Answer (score -2):

Booleans when converted to numeric are 0 and 1.

```
df$boolean <- as.numeric(df$factor)
```

Comment: Your method depends on the type of `df$factor`. It's better to specify how `df$factor` is defined. E.g. `df <- data.frame(factor = ???)`